# one click calls both Click and LinkClicked event handlers

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling, click, linklabel

```
LinkLabel label = new LinkLabel();
// imagine there is a code to initialize the label
label.Click += (sender, args) => callback1();
label.LinkClicked += (sender, args) => callback2();
```

If I click the label anywhere but not its link then `callback1()` is called which is correct.
If I click the label's link then both `callback1()` and `callback2()` are called.

How do I make it call `callback2()` only?

Comment: use two separate labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions I can think of.  First one is a very silly one but looks pretty effective.  You don't like Click when the mouse hovers over a link.  Which has a side-effect, the mouse cursor changes.  So you could filter by checking the cursor shape:

```
private void linkLabel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (Cursor.Current == Cursors.Default) {
       Debug.WriteLine("Click!");
       // etc...
    }
}
```

A bit more principled and handy if you have a lot of link labels is to not raise the Click event at all if the mouse is over a link.  Add a new class to your project and paste this code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class LinkLabelEx : LinkLabel {
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e) {
        var loc = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        if (this.PointInLink(loc.X, loc.Y) == null) base.OnClick(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: The cursor idea is simply great and does exactly what I wanted. Note that when you mark a link using tab on keyboard and press enter then only LinkClicked is called while if you click the link then both Click and LinkClicked are called. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ah, that's true.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a way to do that.

As you can see in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/LinkLabel.cs,4b6d5c50940bb746), `LinkLabel` is derived from `Label`. The `Click` event is raised by the `Label` base class. You can see in the code that the base methods like `OnMouseDown` and `OnMouseUp` are always called before the `LinkLabel` handles those events.

So the `Label` base implementation will always raise a `Click` event before the `LinkClicked` implementation raises the `LinkLabel` event. There is no property or flag to prevent that.

You hopefully can achieve what you want in a different way.